# All CiviCRM public pages on a Wordpress site redirecting to a blank page

Tags: wordpress, migration

We just had a new WordPress site developed and I am now migrating our CiviCRM instance to that site. The old site was also Wordpress. We have worked though all issues except that all the CiviCRM public pages redirect. For example, a contribution page redirects from:

.../civicrm/contribute/transact/?reset=1&id=1 >>> .../civicrm/?reset=1&id=1

and a profile page redirects from:

.../civicrm/profile/create/?gid=14&reset=1 >>> .../civicrm/?gid=14&reset=1

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have CMS page setup in CiviCRM

Comment: Yes... I do have the page setup. /civicrm

Comment: Cleanurl setup?

Comment: Yes... Clean URLs

Comment: I think I found the issue. The developers are using a plugin "Permalink Manager Lite". If I disable that plugin, the pages work.